# Help using JOIN in a SELECT statement

Tags: sql

I am trying to join TABLE_1 and TABLE_2, I need to use every one of these fields in my HTML table.  I am getting an error about my FROM clause, but I believe there are more errors involved.

```
                           "SELECT "
                            + "TABLE_1.id, "
                            + "TABLE_1.date, "
                            + "TABLE_1.location, "
                            + "TABLE_1.name, "
                            + "TABLE_1.status "
                            + "TABLE_2.date, "
                            + "TABLE_2.location, "
                            + "TABLE_2.name, "
                            + "TABLE_2.type "
                         + "FROM SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1 JOIN SCHEMA_1.TABLE_2 "
                         + "WHERE TABLE_1.id = TABLE_2.id "
                         + "AND add_user = ?");
```

Comment: When you use the JOIN statement you need to join it based on the actual columns so you use ON myField1 = myField2.  WHERE is used to filter the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, instead:

```
                       "SELECT "
                        + "TABLE_1.id, "
                        + "TABLE_1.date, "
                        + "TABLE_1.location, "
                        + "TABLE_1.name, "
                        + "TABLE_1.status "
                        + "TABLE_2.date, "
                        + "TABLE_2.location, "
                        + "TABLE_2.name, "
                        + "TABLE_2.type "
                     + "FROM "
                     + "  SCHEMA_1.TABLE_1 JOIN SCHEMA_1.TABLE_2 "
                     + "  ON TABLE_1.ID = TABLE_2.ID"
                     + "WHERE add_user = ?");
```

Answer (score 3):

Change the `WHERE TABLE_1.id = TABLE_2.id AND add_user = ?` for `ON TABLE_1.id = TABLE_2.id WHERE add_user = ?`

Comment: Dumb mistake by me, thank you! It has been forever since I have used SQL.

Comment: Hmmm, I made this change in my code, and I am still getting the error:  ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected.  Could this stem from anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Join the tables by ON not where

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join_inner.asp